# How to not trigger `m2m_changed` signal when updating many to many relationship in Django?

Tags: django, django-signals, m2m

### The Use Case

In my case, I have two signals that are listening on two 2 m2m fields, each of those fields are in different models. The problem happens when one signal is triggered, it triggers the other signal and vice versa, which will result in a recursive loop which will never ends. I need a convenient way to run one signal without triggering the second signal.

### Understand More

If you are curious to know how this case could happen: I have two models which I need to make them mutually synced; if I updated the m2m field in the one model, I need those changes to be reflected on another m2m field in another model and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `set` instead of: `add`, `remove`, or `clear`. Because all of these trigger `m2m_changed` signal multiple times.

This is not mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set) talking about `set` or the [part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) talking about `m2m_changed`